# How do I fix css not working on mobile phone?

Tags: html, css

I have an web site which on pc works perfeclty fine, even when i use inpect element to see the view from a phone, everything is working, but when i see the website on the phone, its like trash, the style sheet isn't working for some elements but for other is. The header on the PC is fine, but then on the phone it appears like it doesnt has style sheet connecting, can anyone help me? please?

I have researching online but i've found a solution yet.

[Here is on the PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx3vl.jpg)

[Here is on the phone mode in PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2V9V.png)

[And here is on the mobile phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hap0W.jpg)

My Code here:

```css
body{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(60deg, #1d1e1f 0%, #394758 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

a {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

#slider{
    background-color: #353333;
    width:100%;
    height:0;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px;
    top: 8%;
    padding:0px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
}

#coiming_soon{
    background-color: #353333;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
}

#s1,#s2,#s3,#s4,#s5{
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    filter: blur(15px);
}

#buscador{
    width:960px;
    margin:410px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#fbuscador{
    display:flex;
    border:1px solid #353333;
    border-radius:15px;
    padding:20px;
}

.divbusca{
    margin:auto;
    display:inline;
}

label{
    display:block;
}

.titulo{
    font-size:22px;
    color:#BBB;
    padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #932727;
  }
  
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: linear-gradient(60deg, #5f84ad 0%, #0d5ebb 100%);
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
  
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
  }

#H1Index {
    text-align:center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 55vh;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-style: Arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #ff1629;
}

#PTextIndex {
    text-align:center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: Arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#PTextIndex1 {
    text-align:center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 174px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: Arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#thumb-image-loaded {
    margin-left: 350px;
    width: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
}

#services .services {
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 450px 0;
}
#services .service-top {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#services .service-bottom {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#services .service-item {
    flex-basis: 80%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: url(./img/img-1.png);
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 10px 5%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#services .service-item::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #29323c 0%, #b12739 100%);
    opacity: 0.9;
    z-index: -1;
}
#services .service-bottom .icon {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#services .service-item h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#services .service-item p {
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 20px;
}


#Gamesh1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: Lucida;
    font-size: 60px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

#pGamesText {
    color: white;
    font-family: Lucida;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.button {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.middle h1 {
    color: #ff1629;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}

@import url("https://font.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(60deg, #394758,#1d1e1f) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.3rem 10%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 100;
}

.header::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    backdrop-filter: blur(50px);
    z-index: -1;
}

.header::after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, rgba(255, 255, 255, .4), transparent );
    transition: .5s;
}

.header:hover::after {
    left: 100%;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar a {
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 2.5rem;
}

#check {
    display: none;
}

.icons {
    font-size: 2.8rem;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

/*breakpoints*/

@media (max-width: 1218px) {
    .header {
        padding: 1.3rem 5%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1086px) {
    .icons {
        display: inline-flex;
    }

    #check:checked~.icons #menu-icon {
        display: none;
    }

    #check:checked~.icons #close-icon {
        display: block;
    }

    .icons #close-icon {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
        background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
        backdrop-filter: blur(50px);
        box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: .3s ease;
    }
    
    #check:checked~.navbar {
        height: 14.7rem;
    }

    .navbar a {
        display: block;
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        margin: 1.5rem 0;
        text-align: center;
        transform: translateX(-50px);
        transform: translateY(-50px);
        transition: .3s ease;
    }

    #check:checked~.navbar a {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
        transition-delay: calc(.06s * var(--i));
        
    }  

}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  *, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  
  .column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    padding: 0 8px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .column {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
  }
  
  .card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  
  .container {
    padding: 0 16px;
  }
  
  .container::after, .row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
  }
  
  .title {
    color: grey;
  }
  
  .button {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .button:hover {
    background-color: #555;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=“en”>
<head>
    <title>Overload Games</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css"/> 
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
</head>
<body>
    
    <header class="header">
        <a href="#" class="logo" id="logo">Overload Games</a>

        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <label for="check" class="icons">
            <i class='bx bx-menu' id="menu-icon"></i>
            <i class='bx bx-x' id="close-icon"></i>
        </label>

        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="index.html" style="--i:0;">Home</a>
            <a href="about.php" style="--i:1;">About Us</a>
            <a href="Games.php" style="--i:2;">Games</a>
            <a href="support.php" style="--i:3;">Support</a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/Indie_Overload" style="--i:4;">Twitter</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

        <section id="slider">
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var slides=["#s1","#s2","#s3"];
            slideatual=0;
            slidemax=2;
            tempo=5000;
                
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(slides[slideatual]).fadeTo(1000,1);
                setInterval(troca,tempo);   
                function troca(){
                    $(slides[slideatual]).fadeTo(1000,0);
                    slideatual++;
                    if(slideatual > slidemax){
                        slideatual=0;
                    }
                    $(slides[slideatual]).fadeTo(1000,1);
                }
            });
                
        </script>

        <img id="s1" src="slides/slide1.jpg"/>
        <img id="s2" src="slides/slide1.jpg"/>
        <img id="s3" src="slides/slide1.jpg"/>

    </section>

    <h1 id="H1Index">WE CREATE GAMES WITH LOVE</h1>

    <p id="PTextIndex"> </p>
    <p id="PTextIndex"> </p>
    <!--Rise Of The Infected, a narrative adventure set in the future during an apocalypse, coming out to Steam.-->

    <p id="PTextIndex1">Established in 2017, Overload Games, is a small team and we love what we do and we make lovingly crafted games .</p>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us just enough code to demonstrate the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Having said that, my suspicion is you are lacking a meta tag. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: @AHaworth i've put it now on the question